# How to get touched shape (arc) from Android canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I'm building a custom view.

It has 4 arcs.

I'm drawing arcs using a `RectF` shape, during `onDraw()`:

```
// arcPaint is a Paint object initialized
// in the View's constructor
arcPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
arcPaint.setColor(arcColor);

// Draw arcs, arc1, arc2, arc3 & arc4 are
// measured and initialized during onMeasure()
canvas.drawArc(arc1, startAngle, arc1Angle, false, arcPaint);
canvas.drawArc(arc2, startAngle, arc2Angle, false, arcPaint);
canvas.drawArc(arc3, startAngle, arc3Angle, false, arcPaint);
canvas.drawArc(arc4, startAngle, arc4Angle, false, arcPaint);
```

So, the result is:

[image]

If I draw the `RectF` objects using `canvas.drawRect()` with this code:

```
canvas.drawRect(arc1, arcPaint);
canvas.drawRect(arc2, arcPaint);
canvas.drawRect(arc3, arcPaint);
canvas.drawRect(arc4, arcPaint);
```

the result is this:

[image]

Drawing all together, arcs and rects, gives this:

[image]

I know I can override the `onTouchEvent()` method and get the X, Y coordinates, but I don't know how every coordinate relates to each shape drawn in the canvas.

What I want to do, is to detect when an arc, not a rect, is touched within the `canvas`, how can I achieve that?

**Edit:**

By, *not a rect*, I mean, I don't want to detect when the user touches these areas (the corners of the rect):

[image]

Comment: **Interesting Question**

Comment: It's not really clear what you're after, here. You want to register touches on the arcs, but not the rectangles? What about the overlaps where the arcs touch their bounding rectangles, or the rectangles of other arcs?

Comment: See edit @MikeM.

Comment: Visual aids help so much. :-) So, if I'm following you correctly, you're just trying to emphasize that `Rect#contains(x, y)` won't work for you, yeah?

Comment: Yep, you're right. `Rect#contains(x, y)` doesn't help.

Comment: OK. Are the bounding rectangles always going to be square, and the arcs, perfect circles? Also, is there a particular reason you're not using `drawCircle()` or `drawOval()` instead? I mean, will those ever be incomplete, or open?

Comment: Yes, rects are always square.
Kind of, arcs will be open (270 degrees).
Yes, I will always draw arcs of 270 degrees.

Comment: Ah, good, square. That simplifies things quite a bit. First, you have the center point, or at least you can get it from the `RectF` methods `centerX()`/`centerY()`. You can then figure the distance from that to the touch point with the basic distance formula: distance = sqrt(dx² + dy²). Then, if the absolute value of the difference of that distance and the arc's radius is less than/equal to half the `Paint`'s stroke width, the touch is on that arc. Follow me? Should be easy enough to check if the touch is in the open 90°, and ignore it there.

Comment: What's `d` in `dx²` and `dy²`?

Comment: Difference. Sorry, I was trying to save some characters, and I thought a delta would be even less clear. `dx` is the difference of the x-coordinate of one point, and the x-coordinate of the other.

Comment: So... `distance = sqrt(  (touchX - centerX)²   +   (touchY - centerY)²  )`  ?

Comment: Yep, that's it. I'm on a mobile, atm, otherwise I'd be giving you some code, but I'm pretty sure my reasoning is correct. I'll check it when I get a chance later on.

Comment: I'm giving it a try. I'll keep you posted ;-)

Comment: Didn't work. Almost 2am here, I'll try later today.

Comment: I just threw together a quick test, and it's working for me. I can polish it up into something useable, if you like.

Comment: That'd be super helpful... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This basically boils down to comparing distances from the center point of that figure. Since the bounding rectangles will always be square, one of those distances is essentially fixed, which makes this much easier.

The general methodology here is to calculate the distance from the center point to the touch point, and check if the difference of that distance and the arc's radius is within half of the stroke width either way.

```
private static boolean isOnRing(MotionEvent event, RectF bounds, float strokeWidth) {
    // Figure the distance from center point to touch point.
    final float distance = distance(event.getX(), event.getY(),
                                    bounds.centerX(), bounds.centerY());

    // Assuming square bounds to figure the radius.
    final float radius = bounds.width() / 2f;

    // The Paint stroke is centered on the circumference,
    // so the tolerance is half its width.
    final float halfStrokeWidth = strokeWidth / 2f;

    // Compare the difference to the tolerance.
    return Math.abs(distance - radius) <= halfStrokeWidth;
}

private static float distance(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
    return (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2));
}
```

In the `onTouchEvent()` method, `isOnRing()` is simply called with the `MotionEvent`, the arc's bounding `RectF`, and the `Paint`'s stroke width. For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (isOnRing(event, arc1, arcPaint.getStrokeWidth())) {
                // Hit.
            }
            break;
            ...
    }
    ...
}
```

This by itself will only determine if the touch point is anywhere on the complete ring described by the radius and stroke width. That is, it doesn't account for "gaps" in the arc. There are multiple ways to handle that, if needed.

If you intend to have the start and sweep angles flush with the x/y axes, the simplest method would probably be to check the signs on the differences in the coordinates of the touch point and center point. In broad terms, if the *touch x* minus the *center x* is positive, then you're on the right side; if negative, you're on the left. Similarly figuring for top or bottom will allow you to determine in which quadrant the touch occurred, and whether to ignore the event.

```
final float dx = event.getX() - arc1.centerX();
final float dy = event.getY() - arc1.centerY();

if (dx > 0) {
    // Right side
}
else {
    // Left side
}
...
```

However, if either angle is not to be coterminal with an axis, then the math is a little more involved. For example:

```
private static boolean isInSweep(MotionEvent event, RectF bounds,
                                 float startAngle, float sweepAngle) {
    // Figure atan2 angle.
    final float at =
        (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(event.getY() - bounds.centerY(),
                                          event.getX() - bounds.centerX()));

    // Convert from atan2 to standard angle.
    final float angle = (at + 360) % 360;

    // Check if in sweep.
    return angle >= startAngle && angle <= startAngle + sweepAngle;
}
```

The `if` in `onTouchEvent()` would then change to incorporate both checks.

```
if (isOnRing(event, arc1, arcPaint.getStrokeWidth()) &&
    isInSweep(event, arc1, startAngle, arc1Angle)) {
    // Hit.
}
```

These methods could easily be combined into one, but they're left separate here for clarity's sake.